# How to make a function into a class or module in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I am just learning how to use classes in my projects. I have been working on a DataAccessClass.cs and am doing well (I think).
Taking a break from data access, I decided to try to make a void into a class. This void sends a message to the client as a javascript alert. It works well, but has to be included on each page. When I tried to make it a class, I was informed that my class does not contain a definition for ClientScript. I included all the "using" directives from the original page to no avail... Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The original code:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Name: SendErrorMessageToClient
//Abstract: show alert on client side
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

protected void SendErrorMessageToClient(string strErrorType, string strErrorMessage)
{
    string strMessageToClient = "";

    //Allow single quotes on client-side in JavaScript
    strErrorMessage = strErrorMessage.Replace("'", "\\'");

    strMessageToClient = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\">alert( '" + strErrorType + "\\n\\n" + strErrorMessage + "' );</script>";

    this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ErrorMessage", strMessageToClient);

}
```

Messages are sent into this void like this:

```
if (DataAccessClass.OpenSqlConnection(ref Conn, strConn, out strErrorMessage) == false)
        {
            string strErrorType = "Database Connection Error:";
            SendErrorMessageToClient(strErrorType, strErrorMessage);
        }
```

Or this:

```
catch (Exception excError)
    {
        string strErrorType = "Unhandled Exception:";
        string strErrorMessage = excError.Message;
        SendErrorMessageToClient(strErrorType, strErrorMessage);
    }
```

Comment: In this.ClientScript the 'this' is referencing the current page object instance. If you put that code into a separate class, the class has no way of knowing what ClientScript is unless your new class inherits System.Web.UI.Page. But you would still need to pass to it a reference of the current page instance for it to be able to operate on the page in question.

Comment: What does the code look like for your new class definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving the error as 'Clientscript' is a property derived from a System.Web.UI.Page and by moving into a separate class file, you no longer have access to this property.

You could solve this by passing in the page as well, and amending the code to

```
protected void SendErrorMessageToClient(string strErrorType, string strErrorMessage, Page page)
{
    string strMessageToClient = "";

    //Allow single quotes on client-side in JavaScript
    strErrorMessage = strErrorMessage.Replace("'", "\\'");

    strMessageToClient = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\">alert( '" + strErrorType + "\\n\\n" + strErrorMessage + "' );</script>";

    page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ErrorMessage", strMessageToClient);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ClientScript` Property is part of the `Page` class that every `ASPX` page inherit from. Therefore you can not just use it from inside your class unless it (i.e. your class) has `Page` as its base class.

Answer (score 0):

`this.` is for fields in your method in classes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass the page into the function

```
SendErrorMessageToClient(Page page, string strErrorType, string strErrorMessage)
```

so that you can change

```
this.ClientScript...
```

to

```
page.ClientScript...
```

The reason being that ClientScript is part of the Page class

Or, possibly better, pass the ClientScript object, rather than page.
So your definition would look like

```
SendErrorMessageToClient(ClientScript clientScript, string strErrorType, string strErrorMessage) {
    string strMessageToClient = "";

    //Allow single quotes on client-side in JavaScript
    strErrorMessage = strErrorMessage.Replace("'", "\\'");

    strMessageToClient = String.Format("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>alert('{0}\\n\\n{1}');</script>",
                                        strErrorType, strErrorMessage);

    clientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ErrorMessage", strMessageToClient);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to return a string?  Then display the string using the current method?

Comment: @Ramhound, not with a method named `SendErrorMessageToClient`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to make this a class? It shouldn't be a class, it doesn't have any properties or fields, unless you can think of one.  You do understand if you make it a class you would still have to intialize it on every page.

You could make it a static string method you would still have to include this on every page.

**this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ErrorMessage", strMessageToClient);**

Comment: I have put things like this into modules in VB, but have not found an equivalent construct in C#. I just am trying to eliminate repetitive code.